# Convert DD-MM-YY to DD-MM-YYYY using sub/function

Tags: vba

I have been given a list of enrollment dates for some sources for an assignment.
They want me to change the dates using vba
The question is:

"As with the previous assignment that the Director gave you, the enrollment date is in a “not normal” format. The director wants the date changed into the “normal” Danish format “DD-MM-YYYY”. You, therefore, must create a sub/function that changes the date in the field to the “correct” format. As the function needs to be able to run multiple times you should use the appropriate selection statements to check that the date is in the “not normal” format before converting it."

I have attached a picture of the excel
[image: img1]

Comment: "appropriate selection statements", nice oxymoron. The date is "not normal format" for sure, it's a `String`, not `Date`. The correct way to go about this, is to use `DateSerial` on parts of this string, fill column with these processed dates and then format column so that it displays dates in any format you like.

Answer (score 0):

This function appends a `20` before the year part if its only 2 characters.

```
Function DateConvert(BtVal dt As String) As String
Dim parts As String()
parts = Split(dt, "-")
dd = parts(1)
mm = parts(2)
yy = parts(3)
DateConvert = dd & "-" & mm & "-" & IIf (Len(yy) = 2, "20" & yy, yy)
End Function
```

You might want to extend this logic, for example `"65"` can be replaced with `"1965"` instead of `"2065"`, but I leave that part to you.

Comment: In my opinion, writing date to cell in text format is no way to go. How to sort it or do any other operations? And this distracting green triangle in cell corner on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

The function will test whether the string matches the pattern. If it does, it returns formatted date, otherwise it returns same cell's value.

```
Function GetDate(cell)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$"
        With .Execute(cell)
            If .Count > 0 Then
                With .Item(0)
                    GetDate = Format(DateSerial(.SubMatches(2), .SubMatches(1), .SubMatches(0)), "dd-MM-yyyy")
                End With
            Else
                GetDate = cell
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Function
```